# bad argument #1 to pairs (table expected, got nil)

Tags: lua

okay so I'm trying to fix this bug/error but I'm completely stuck,
So if someone as any idea you're more then welcome to share your option with me,

```lua
function VehicleList(isDown)
    ped = GetPlayerPed(-1);
    MenuTitle = "Voertuigen:"
    local grade = RSCore.Functions.GetPlayerData().job.grade
    ClearMenu()
    for veh, label in pairs(Config.Vehicles) do
        Menu.addButton(label, "TakeOutVehicle", veh, "Garage", " Motor: 100%", " Body: 100%", " Fuel: 100%")
    end
        
    if IsArmoryWhitelist() then
        for veh, label in pairs(Config.WhitelistedVehicles) do
            Menu.addButton(label, "TakeOutVehicle", veh, "Garage", " Engine: 100%", " Body: 100%", " Fuel: 100%")
        end
    end
        
    Menu.addButton("Terug", "MenuGarage",nil)
end
```

Comment: which of the 2 `pairs` functions is causing the error?

Comment: `for veh, label in pairs(Config.Vehicles or {}) do`

Answer (score 3):

`pairs` only works on table values. Hence calling it with a nil value causes an error.

There are basically 3 things you could do here.

1. find out why you get a nil value instead of a table and fix that
2. do not call `pairs` by putting your generic for loop inside a conditional statement
3. replace `pairs` argument with a default table, for example an emtpy table

2:

```
if type(Config.Vehicles) == "table" then
  for veh, label in pairs(Config.Vehicles) do
    Menu.addButton(label, "TakeOutVehicle", veh, "Garage",
      " Motor: 100%", " Body: 100%", " Fuel: 100%")
  end
end
```

3: only works if table is either a table or nil/false

```
for veh, label in pairs(Config.Vehicles or {}) do
  Menu.addButton(label, "TakeOutVehicle", veh, "Garage",
    " Motor: 100%", " Body: 100%", " Fuel: 100%")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table is actually returning a `nil` value, so `pairs` function won't work. You can fix this creating a condition, like this:

```
if (table ~= nil) then -- condition
    for ... in pairs(table) do
            
    end
end
```

Comment: okey so should i just removing the  for k, v in pairs(Config.Vehicles[grade]) do  and replacing with your version or just under neef it ?

Comment: No! This is just a sample code. My answer just tell you to create a condition that prevent the error in your code. Look the line that I added "-- condition", this line creates a condition that will ignore the pairs function if the table is nil. This should solve the error.

Comment: where can i place that "--condition", function because still while placing the condition function I'm getting the bad argument #1

Comment: tables do not "return" values.

Answer (score 0):

okey so basically it should working like this,

```
function VehicleList(isDown)
ped = GetPlayerPed(-1);
MenuTitle = "Voertuigen:"
local grade = RSCore.Functions.GetPlayerData().job.grade
ClearMenu()
for k, v in pairs(Config.Vehicles[grade]) do
    Menu.addButton(v, "TakeOutVehicle", k, "Garage", " Motor: 100%", " Body: 100%", " Fuel: 100%")
end
```

but while removing the [grade] part at the line for k, v in pairs(Config.Vehicles[grade]) do I'm able to open the vehicle list inside the game but I'm not able to spawn them at all
the [grade] part that's getting me the bad argument #1